# Opening the moderator menu results in an empty red box

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, mobile-web

Opening the moderator menu on mobile without accepting the moderator agreement results in an empty red box.

On desktop, it correctly displays a notice that you must accept the moderator agreement.

> [image: bug]

After accepting the agreement, the issue goes away.

I'm using Chrome on Android. (Not the Android app.)